# Error al enviar datos de consulta Linqc# a la vista HTML

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Tengo una consulta Linq que me regresa ciertos datos, pera al pasarlo a la vista tira el siguiente error:

> El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType12`17[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Int16,System.Nullable`1[System.Int16],System.Decimal,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int16],System.String]]', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyProject.Models.Muestras]'.

Mi modelo:

```html
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Muestras
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public short Empresa { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public short Campo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha_solicitud { get; set; }
      }
}
```

My controller

```html
public ActionResult Home()
{
var item = from m in bd.Muestras
          join p in bd.Personas on m.Codigo equals p.Codigo
          join c in bd.Campos on new { m.Codigo, m.Campo } equals new {c.Codigo, c.Campo }
          join l in bd.Localidades on c.CodLocalidad equals l.CodLocalidad                          
          
          select new {
          Asesor= p.Nombre,
          Codigo = m.Codigo,              
          Campo = m.Campo,
          Campo=c.Descripcion
          };
             
return View(item.ToList());
}
```

Vista

```html
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Muestras>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<table class="table table-hover">
 @if (Model != null)
 {
 <thead class="thead-light">
 <tr>
   <th>Codigo</th>
   <th>Asesor</th>      
   ...
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
  <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Codigo)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Personas.Nombre)</td>
    ..etc
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  }
 }
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la vista esta esperando un objeto de tipo `Muestras` mientras que tu en el controlador le estas enviando un anonimo, lo que tienes que cambiar en tu controlador es lo siguiente:

```
public ActionResult Home()
{
          var item = from m in bd.Muestras
          join p in bd.Personas on m.Codigo equals p.Codigo
          join c in bd.Campos on new { m.Codigo, m.Campo } equals new {c.Codigo, c.Campo }
          join l in bd.Localidades on c.CodLocalidad equals l.CodLocalidad                          
          
          select new Muestras {
          Codigo = m.Codigo,              
          Campo = m.Campo,
          etc..
          };
             
     return View(item.ToList());
}
```

En el select de la consulta declaras que el objeto que vas a crear es de tipo `Muestras` y dentro de el mapeas los datos de tu consulta con los del objeto `Muestras` ya que sin eso te va a regresar un objeto anonimo y te va a dar el error que estas mencionando.